# HTML/CSS rendering problems on google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm learning PHP right now (after learning the basics of HTML,CSS and more).
I'm trying to build a website, in which you can cut the main section in to three pieces (one with 15% width, one with 70% width and another one with 15% width).

The problem is that both of the 15% sections work fine on Internet Explorer and Firefox, but for some unknown reason disappears on Google Chrome.

This is the HTML part of the code:

```
    <!-- First Section (Desktop only) -->
    <div class="side_banner">
        <img src="images/asd.gif" id="bannerlong"/>
        <img src="images/asd2.png" id="bannerwide"/>
    </div>
```

And this is the CSS part of the code:

```
.side_banner {
    width: 15%;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 120px;
}

.side_banner img {
    padding: 10px;
}    

#bannerwide {
    display: none;
}

.phone_banner {
    display: none;
}
```

The ones with the "display: none;" are for other viewports...

**An important clue might be that when the file had an HTML extension it worked fine on chrome, but when I changed it to a PHP extension (and opened it through WAMP) the problem appeared.**

Can you please help me find out why there is a problem with my web on Chrome?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hehe yeah... Actually HTML but still understandable ;P

Comment: An important notice! - The rendering was just fine when the file was an HTML file and not with a PHP extension...

Comment: ....that's some intriguing PHP you've got there

Comment: I got nothing. You need to post your entire clock of html and the rendering css to go with it.